# Por qué sale este Warning al ejecutar la consulta por PDO?

Tags: php, web, pdo

Hola espero y puedan ilustrarme con esta duda , trato de realizar una consulta a la base de datos por medio de PDO.  en controlador en vio los siguientes datos como muestra la imagen.

```
        static public function RegistraAspiranteCont(){
        
            if(isset($_POST['registro'])){
                $dato = array(

                    "escuelaProc" => $_POST['escuelaProc'], "muni" => $_POST['municipio'], "estadoDom" => $_POST['estado'], "carrera" => $_POST['carrera'],
                    "tipoDisca" => $_POST['tipoDisca'], "aP" => $_POST['apellidoP'], "aM" => $_POST['apellidoM'], "nomAl" => $_POST['nombre'], 
                    "fechNac" => $_POST['fecha_nac'], "genero" => $_POST['genero'],"discapacidad" => $_POST['discapacidad'],"dir" => $_POST['Direc'], 
                    "col" => $_POST['colonia'],"loc" => $_POST['localidad'], "curp" => $_POST['curp'],"cel" => $_POST['cel'], "email" => $_POST['email'], 
                    "observacion" => $_POST['observacion'],"anioE" => $_POST['anioE'], "cp" => $_POST['cp'], "EdoCivil" => $_POST['EdoCivil'], 
                    "nivelSoc" => $_POST['nivelSoc'], "tel" => $_POST['tel'], "edoNac" => $_POST['edoNac'], "sh" => $_POST['sh'], "fechaR" => $_POST['fecha'], "cu" => $_POST['cu'], "ca" => $_POST['ca'], "fll" => $_POST['fll'], "fotos" => $_POST['fotos'], "folio" => $_POST['folio'], "estatusPago"=> $_POST['estatusPago']    
                );

                $resultado = AspirantesModel::RegistraAspiranteMdl($dato,"ASPIRANTES");
    
                echo $resultado;
            }

    
        }
```

esa información se manda al modelo de la siguiente manera

```
  static public function RegistraAspiranteMdl($datos,$tbl){    

      $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tbl VALUES (null,? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? ,? , ? , ? ,? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?, ?)");

        $stmt->bindParam(":escuelaProc", $datos["escuelaProc"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":muni", $datos["muni"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
          $stmt->bindParam(":estadoDom", $datos["estadoDom"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
          $stmt->bindParam(":carrera", $datos["carrera"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
          $stmt->bindParam(":tipoDisca", $datos["tipoDisca"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
          $stmt->bindParam(":aP", $datos["aP"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindParam(":aM", $datos["aM"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindParam(":nomAl", $datos["nomAl"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindParam(":fechNac", $datos["fechNac"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindParam(":genero", $datos["genero"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindParam(":discapacidad", $datos["discapacidad"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindParam(":dir", $datos["dir"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindParam(":col", $datos["col"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindParam(":loc", $datos["loc"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindParam(":curp", $datos["curp"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindParam(":cel", $datos["cel"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindParam(":email", $datos["email"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindParam(":observacion", $datos["observacion"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindParam(":anioE", $datos["anioE"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindParam(":cp", $datos["cp"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindParam(":EdoCivil", $datos["EdoCivil"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindParam(":nivelSoc", $datos["nivelSoc"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindParam(":tel", $datos["tel"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindParam(":edoNac", $datos["edoNac"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
          $stmt->bindParam(":sh", $datos["sh"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindParam(":fechaR", $datos["fechaR"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindParam(":cu", $datos["cu"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindParam(":ca", $datos["ca"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindParam(":fll", $datos["fll"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindParam(":fotos", $datos["fotos"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindParam(":folio", $datos["folio"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindParam(":estatusPago", $datos["estatusPago"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        
        if($stmt -> execute()){
            return "ok";
        }else{
               return "error";
          } 
   }
```

al momento de insertar los datos al la base de datos, me muestra el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error es:

```
 PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:
```

espero y me puedan ayudar, ya puse de cabeza el código, ya revise los tipos de datos etc. :C

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], tanto el código como el mensaje de error van como texto

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. En vez de pegar las imágenes, dale a [edit](/edit) e incluye el código en texto, según las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Comment: cuantos campos tiene tu tabla `ASPIRANTES`??

Comment: tengo 32, sin contar la id, en la inserción agregue el null para probar pero nada.

Comment: Cómo está definida la tabla de destino? el campo ID es auto_increment o similar? En qué BD estás probando?

Comment: es auto_incremen amigo estoy en mysql server

Comment: Estás creando la cadena de consulta con marcas `?`, pero intentas enlazar parámetros por nombre y, como no existe el nombre en la cadena, recibes el mensaje de error.